# The info about new Tango()

Tags: google-project-tango

I have downloaded the demo "java_quick_start_example".
1. I run the app directly, but it is failed. The log is described as 
`TangoErrorType  TangoService_initialize (JNIEnv*, jobject): Done initializing, error code = -1`
2. I modify the code as below

```
 mTango = new Tango(this, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
          }
 });
```

It is failed, too. The log is described as `"Error - TangoService_connectOnPoseAvailable: -1"`

Answer (score 0):

some example pull from Tango Example :

```
 mTango = new Tango(MotionTrackingActivity.this, new Runnable() {
        // Pass in a Runnable to be called from UI thread when Tango is ready,
        // this Runnable will be running on a new thread.
        // When Tango is ready, we can call Tango functions safely here only
        // when there is no UI thread changes involved.
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mConfig = setupTangoConfig(mTango);

            try {
                setTangoListeners();
            } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_error), e);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.permission_motion_tracking), e);
            }
            try {
                mTango.connect(mConfig);
            } catch (TangoOutOfDateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_out_of_date), e);
            } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_error), e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```